# Sagemaker neo Json input

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I was able to compile the XGBoost model using Sagemaker Neo; However, the original model without Neo compilation used Json for Input/Output. After compiling and deploying the model it is only accepting the text/csv content type. It is not accepting the Json input.

```
xgboost_model = XGBoostModel(
    role=role,
    model_data=model_s3_location,
    entry_point=inference.py,
    source_dir=model_s3_src,
    framework_version=version)
```

Compiling the model with Neo

```
neo_model = xgboost_model.compile(
    target_instance_family="ml_c5",
    role=role,
    input_shape =f'{{"data": [1, 61]}}',
    output_path ='s3://bucket/neo/model-neo.tar.gz'
    framework = "xgboost",
    job_name='neo3'
)
```

Deploy the Neo model

```
predictor = xgboost_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type=ml.c5.2xlarge,
    serializer=JSONSerializer(),
    endpoint_name='neo',
    deserializer=StringDeserializer())
```

When I pass in the Json request

```
predictor.predict(test_json)
```

I get the following error

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "ClientError: Invalid content type. Accepted content types are "text/libsvm" and "text/csv". Received application/json".
```

Without Neo compilation everything works fine, but slow. How do I make sure Neo compiled model still accepts the JSON content-type?